# c# use a function on a generic type with ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewmodel

Is this possible?  I am trying to avoid a lot of copying and pasting from area to area.  I have a search function (I have reduced the code for simplicity).

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterVM.searchString))
            {
                var nameSearch = filterVM.searchString.ToLower();
                guests = guests.Where(g => g.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(nameSearch)
                || g.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(nameSearch)
                )
            }

            filterVM.FilteredResultsCount = guests.CountAsync();
```

Guests can change from area to area, but it always has the same base things, like FirstName and LastName,
ex:

```
public class GuestBasicBase
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string GuestGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can have a bigger class for a particular area like

```
 public class AreaOneGuest : GuestBasicBase
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public string ExtraFieldOne { get; set; }    
        public string ExtraFieldTwo { get; set; }    
//Etc    
        }
```

I would like to have a function which will return a viewmodel and part of that viewmodel is PaginatedList and the other part is the Filter parameters, like this:

```
public class GuestBasicBaseIndexVM
    {
        public PaginatedList<T:GuestBasicBase> Guests  { get; set; } 

        public GuestIndexFilterVM FilterVM { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want a function to return this but take in a larger field, like

```
public async Task<GuestBasicBaseIndexVM>(T:GuestBasicBase, GuestIndexFilterVM filterVM){
//do search function
return (T where T: GuestBasicBase)
}
```

Does this question make sense and is it possible?  Currently trying on my own and seeing what happens...I feel like it is sort of like the `PaginatedList` class but I am not certain

Comment: Did you checked this link? https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/48061009/using-interfaces-with-dbset--possible-with-ef-core-

Comment: That link might apply, but it is a lot of extra work.  I have put an answer with what i did

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I wanted, but here is what I did.   changed my BaseViewModel like this:

```
    public class GuestBasicBaseIndexVM
        {
            public IEnumerable<GuestBasicBase> Guests  { get; set; } 
            //Changed from a PaginatedList

            public GuestIndexFilterVM FilterVM { get; set; }
        }
```

and this function:

```
public static async Task<GuestBasicBaseIndexVM> CreateUpdatedGuestList(GuestIndexFilterVM filterVM, IQueryable<GuestBasicBase> guests)
{
//Code to search through guests and return filtered list and filters viewmodel
}
```

Then after the Ienumaerable of basic guests is returned I did this to connect them back to the AreaOne Guests

```
var x = await Helpers.CreateUpdatedGuestList(filterVM, guests);
var hsIDs = x.Guests.Select(v => v.GuestGuid).ToHashSet(); //Filtered GuestGuids to hashset

areaOneGuests = guests.Where(g => hsIDs.Contains(g.GuestGuid)) //This matches up the filtered list of base guests to the actual full guests.
//Then whatever code to do what I want with the AreaOne Guests....
```

It wasn't exactly what I was trying to  do, but still saves me a lot of copying and pasting from area to area with similar base Guest classes.  Have not been able to measure any noticeable performance loss/gain doing it this way.